# Java stream filtering List<Map<String,String>>

Tags: java, java-stream

I would like to filter a "List of Map" and create a new object using Streams.

For the first step, I'm able to select the entry from the list that matches a specific key:

```
List<Map<String,String>> listOfItems =...
listOfItems.stream().filter(m -> m.get("name").equals("apple"));
```

Now, I would like to create an object using the selected Map entry.

Thanks,
Sudha

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
List<Map<String,String>> listOfItems =...
listOfItems.stream()
           .filter(m -> m.containsValue("apple"))
           .map(m -> new NewObject(m))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This works if NewObject has an empty constructor. But, not with a map argument. I get this error : incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Map<String,String>

Comment: What do you mean by that? Is NewObject has String constructor?

Comment: No, it has no string constructor. It has a constructor with a Map<String,String>. But in NewObject(m), 'm' is being treated as a String instead of Map.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand your question correctly, you need something like this:

```
List<Map<String,String>> listOfItems =...
List<MyObject> objects = listOfItems
    .stream()
    .filter(m -> m.get("name").equals("apple")) 
    .map(MyObject::new) // Construct object from matching map
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // Collect into list
```

This will create a list of `MyObject` instances, one for each matching map in your original list. If you only expect there to be one such Map, or you only ever want to create an object f om the first matching Map, you can replace the last line with `.findFirst()` (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--)).

Comment: I get an error with this =>  method map in interface Stream<T> cannot be applied to given types at .map(MyObject::new)

Comment: That line assumes you are constructing an object called MyObject, and it has a constructor that takes a single String as an argument. This might have been a false assumption on my part. What object are you trying to construct? With what arguments?

Comment: The Map(k,v) maps to a POJO. I need to pass the map to the object to initialize.